# Handle large contact list with Realm

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, memory, realm

I'm stuck on a memory issue since the beginning of the day. Let me explain. 
I'm handling contacts in a VoIP app, we have two types of contacts, the ones who also have the app, and the one who don't have the app. And we're using Realm in order to manage those contacts (and other things, but this issue is only related to the contacts).

Here is how we do it :

LaunchViewController.swift :

```
sSelf.contactsService = RealmContactService()
sSelf.contactsService?.syncContacts { [weak self] _ in
    guard let sSelf = self else { return }
    sSelf.taskGroup.leave()
}
```

Then in the RealmContactService :

```
func syncContacts(askForPermission: Bool = false, completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    cnContactStoreService.fetchContacts(shouldAskForPermission: askForPermission) { [weak self] (isSuccess, contacts) in
        if isSuccess {
            let realmContacts = contacts.map { cnContact -> RealmContact in
                if let existingContact = self?.fetchContact(withId: cnContact.identifier) {
                    self?.update(contact: existingContact, with: cnContact)
                    return existingContact
                }
                return RealmContact(from: cnContact)
            }
            self?.add(contacts: realmContacts, update: true)
            self?.update(contacts: realmContacts, completion: completion)
        } else {
            completion?(false)
        }
    }
}

private func update(contacts: [RealmContact], completion: ((_ success: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

    let phoneNumbers = contacts.flatMap { contact in
        return contact.phoneNumbers
        }.flatMap { phoneNumber in
            return phoneNumber.phoneNumberE164
    }

    contacts.forEach { (contact) in
        self.realm.beginWrite()
        contact.isAppContact = false
        self.add(contact: contact, update: true)
        try! self.realm.commitWrite()
    }

    APIClient.shared.matchAppPhoneNumber(phoneNumbers: phoneNumbers) { [weak self] response in
        guard let response = response else {
            self?.syncDeletedContacts(completion: completion)
            return
        }

        if let phoneNumbers = response.phoneNumberArray as? [PhoneNumber] {

            phoneNumbers.forEach { updatedNumber in
                contacts.forEach { contact in
                    contact.phoneNumbers.forEach { phoneNumber in
                        if phoneNumber.phoneNumberE164 == updatedNumber.phoneNumber {
                            self?.realm.beginWrite()
                            contact.isAppContact = true
                            phoneNumber.hasApp = true
                            phoneNumber.appAccountId = Int(updatedNumber.accountId)
                            self?.add(contact: contact, update: true)
                            try! self?.realm.commitWrite()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self?.syncDeletedContacts(completion: completion)
    }
}
```

And here are the two 'pure' Realm functions that we use in order to write and update a contact :

```
func add(contact: RealmContact, update: Bool = false) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(contact, update: update)
        }
    }
}

func update(contact: RealmContact, with cnContact: CNContact) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {            
        try! self.realm.write {
            contact.update(from: cnContact)
        }
    }
}
```

With this way, we are having a memory issue like this :

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

*It only crashes on iPhone 6 and below. But it would be awesome to not overuse device memory !*

I know we do not handle it the best way, but I can't find a viable solution and I'd like to get advices on how to optimize this code.

Thanks for your valuable help !